# Shadow for UIButton blures button image

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this code for add shadow to UIButton

```
layer.masksToBounds = false
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Its successfully adds shadow to the button,but also blures the button image
Is it possible to add shadow without bluring button content?

Comment: Did you try to set `layer.shouldRasterize` to `false`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. seems I found the solution just had to add         layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

Comment: But your suggestion is also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is ok, just delete the line layer.shouldRasterize = true or set it to False.

Comment: Yea seems so. Thanks